# How to share text to WhatsApp from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I develop an app with a functionality for sharing text. This is working fine except for WhatsApp. What should I do? Is there any specific API for that?

Comment: Use Android’s sharing mechanism. I can share text just fine with WhatsApp.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

There is no public official api for whats app....So it is not possible now. (answered on 6-Nov-2012)

Comment: it is possible with 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text");
    activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Do not post an answer if you do not know !

Comment: Saqqib is answered on 6-Nov-2012.. Please check the answered date and time before giving down vote and comments.

Answer (score 144):

You can use intent to do so.
No need to use Whatsapp API.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Comment: This is perfect code. Its worked for me and Yes marked answer saving its not possible that is completely wrong. This answer should be marked as Correct answer.

Comment: [I'm an Android developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app?](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012)

Comment: @Eido95 This will not help in case of Whatsapp business app. with package: `com.whatsapp.w4b`. Because lots of the people started using Whatsapp business app now a days.

Answer (score 19):

There are two ways to integrate with WhatsApp:

- Through a custom URL scheme
- Through Android's intent system.

If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so. Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.

Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example, and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

However, if you prefer to share directly to WhatsApp and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using setPackage in your intent:

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

This would simply be set right before you call startActivity(sendIntent);

Please refer below link Official WhatsApp Page:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012,

If you want to share some text to specific WhatsApp contact, Please refer below code.

```
private void openWhatsApp() {
String smsNumber = "7****"; //without '+'
try {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    //sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

}
```

For more details please refer below link 
[Send text to specific contact (whatsapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-whatsapp)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15775379)

Comment: Edited my ans @EJoshuaS

Answer (score 10):

If the user does not have the Whatsapp app in their device then the user will
 get the **ActivityNotFoundException**

Then, you should move the user to download the app first.

```
public void shareViaWhatsApp() {
        Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Application of social rating share with your friend");
        try {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivity(whatsappIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share using"));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure...but i am afraid there is no official API released. I also wanted to implement a "send us a whatsapp" feature, but i am giving up for a while until whatsapp.inc release a official one

There are some no-official API but i do not know if you want that...

http://www.whatsapp-api.com/developers.php

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

good luck....and if you discover something, please let me know ;)

Comment: i think this page is deleted from whatspp website

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WhatsApp API
Android: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012
iOS: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Answer (score 0):

```
 message = "this msg is sent from My App Time Track"
            val intent = Intent()//Empty as we don't know the destination i.e implicit intent
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND//intent will do work of sending something
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)//send given message
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Download Time Track App")//give the subject for your message
            //Intent.Extra_Text is actually a globol key
            intent.type = "plane/text"//type of intent

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send to: "))//createChooser is a dialogBox which shows app available to send data
```