# How to send message to Whatsapp to specified number without opening whatsapp app

Tags: android, message, whatsapp

I want to send message to whatsapp to specified number without opening whatsapp app on button click

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whatsapp doesn't take the text and send it. This functionality is not implemented. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-whatsapp

Comment: I guess there is no way to do so

Comment: but google assistant is already doing this