# Auto Reply to WhatsApp message in background

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp, accessibilityservice

I just checking out the [Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforwa&hl=en_IN), is doing auto reply to WhatsApp message in background. I also trying to doing so, but can't get success in it.
I had tried :

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
 sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
 sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
 sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But it opening the WhatsApp application :(, not sending the message.

I go through with several links: [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254370/how-to-send-message-to-whatsapp-to-specified-number-without-opening-whatsapp-app), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788600/automatic-reply-for-whatsapp-messages-approach?noredirect=1&lq=1) also [article](https://medium.com/@polidea/how-to-respond-to-any-messaging-notification-on-android-7befa483e2d7) on it but not getting satisfactory answer.

The [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforwa&hl=en_IN) are accessing the notifications to get the messages, and replying to it, I also tried reading notifications using `NotificationListenerService`, and got success to read message :), but can't send reply to it, **I want to know how they are sending the messages in the background without opening the application**.

Comment: You need a number to send message. You've to send to a specific number.

Comment: @AAShakil did you check the application, which i mention above in application, it didn't take any user input, it directly reply to WhatsApp message.

Comment: honestly I think they did a workaround to [click to chat](https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/). You can try like opening this in a custom webview and clicking the button by code. But not sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980078/read-notification-bar-title-message-using-accessibility-service-programmaticall

Comment: @Rocky have you got the solution for this !

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this but I think this can be done via 
[Read Notification Bar title, message using Accessibility Service Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980078/read-notification-bar-title-message-using-accessibility-service-programmaticall)

and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RemoteInput

From doc :

```
 public static final String KEY_QUICK_REPLY_TEXT = "quick_reply";
 Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(
         R.drawable.reply, "Reply", actionIntent)
         .addRemoteInput(new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_QUICK_REPLY_TEXT)
                 .setLabel("Quick reply").build())
         .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

On a rooted device you can simply insert a message into the database
`/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db` like this.

Firstly get the contacts from the database. WhatsApp uses its own IDs for contacts(not user numbers) in the `jid` column, will have to get that and the `display name`.

```
 class Contact{
public String jid;
public String displayName;
public Contact(String displayName,String jid){
this.displayName = displayName;
this.jid = jid;
}
}
public List<Contact> getContacts(){
     Shell.SU.run("am force-stop com.whatsapp");
     Shell.SU.run("chmod 777 /data/data/com.whatsapp");
                        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(new File("/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/wa.db"), null);
                        List<Contact> contactList = new LinkedList<>();
                        String selectQuery = "SELECT  jid, display_name FROM wa_contacts where phone_type is not null and is_whatsapp_user = 1";
                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(0));
                                contactList.add(contact);
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        db.close();
}
```

Then send the message like so

```
    private void sendBigMessage(String jid, String msg, String file, String mimeType) {

     Shell.SU.run("am force-stop com.whatsapp");
 db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(new File("/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db"), null);

            long l1;
            long l2;
            int k;
            String query2, query1;

            Random localRandom = new Random(20L);
            l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            l2 = l1 / 1000L;
            k = localRandom.nextInt();

            int mediaType = 0;

            if (mimeType == null || mimeType.length() < 2)
                mediaType = 0;
            else
                mediaType = (mimeType.contains("video")) ? 3
                        : (mimeType.contains("image")) ? 1
                        : (mimeType.contains("audio")) ? 2
                        : 0;

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put("key_remote_jid", jid);
            initialValues.put("key_from_me", 1);
            initialValues.put("key_id", l2 + "-" + k);
            initialValues.put("status", 1);
            initialValues.put("needs_push", 0);
            initialValues.put("timestamp", l1);
            initialValues.put("media_wa_type", mediaType);
            initialValues.put("media_name", file);
            initialValues.put("latitude", 0.0);
            initialValues.put("longitude", 0.0);
            initialValues.put("received_timestamp", l1);
            initialValues.put("send_timestamp", -1);
            initialValues.put("receipt_server_timestamp", -1);
            initialValues.put("receipt_device_timestamp", -1);
            initialValues.put("raw_data", -1);
            initialValues.put("recipient_count", 0);
            initialValues.put("media_duration", 0);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(file) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mimeType)) {
                //boolean isVideo = mimeType.contains("video");
                Bitmap bMap = null;
                File spec;
                if (mediaType == 3) {
                    spec = new File(vidFolder, file);
                    bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(spec.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                } else if(mediaType == 2) {
                    spec = new File(audFolder, file);
                }else{
                    spec = new File(imgFolder, file);
                    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(spec.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                long mediaSize = (file.equals("")) ? 0 : spec.length();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if(mediaType == 1 || mediaType ==3) {
                    bMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 100, 59, false);
                    bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
                }
                byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();

                MediaData md = new MediaData();
                md.fileSize = mediaSize;
                md.file = spec;
                md.autodownloadRetryEnabled = true;
                byte[] arr = SerializationUtils.serialize(md);

                initialValues.put("thumb_image", arr);
                initialValues.put("quoted_row_id", 0);
                //initialValues.put("media_mime_type", mimeType);
                //initialValues.put("media_hash", "9vZ3oZyplgiZ40jJvo/sLNrk3c1fuLOA+hLEhEjL+rg=");
                initialValues.put("raw_data", bArray);
                initialValues.put("media_size", mediaSize);
                initialValues.put("origin", 0);
                initialValues.put("media_caption", msg);
            } else
                initialValues.put("data", msg);

            long idm = db.insert("messages", null, initialValues);

            query1 = " insert into chat_list (key_remote_jid) select '" + jid
                    + "' where not exists (select 1 from chat_list where key_remote_jid='" + jid + "');";

            query2 = " update chat_list set message_table_id = (select max(messages._id) from messages) where chat_list.key_remote_jid='" + jid + "';";


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("docid", idm);
            values.put("c0content", "null  ");
            db.insert("messages_fts_content", null, values);


            db.execSQL(query1 + query2);
 db.close();
        }
```

Comment: I wanted to know to do this on non-rooted device.

Comment: On non rooted devices, there is probably a Broadcast Receiver that Google now and WhatsApp use to communicate. Unfortunately it is not public

Comment: actually this is not working. On my app I have privilege to read and write to external memory, Whatsapp is correctly terminated with the su command, but the command SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase is unable to open the database. I get the following LOG: Error Code : 1806 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES)
    Caused By : Application has no permission to open the specified database file

Comment: @Gaucho I'm currently busy with a lot of work, I'll look at that issue and get back to you

Comment: @Gaucho, call chmod to add the permission `Shell.SU.run("chmod 777 /data/data/com.whatsapp");`. Look at the updated answer

Comment: Oh my god it's online since one year. I love you @niza

Answer (score 0):

After reading the notification, check if it has a reply action then use RemoteInput to reply on the notification.
Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017178/13222541