# How I can replay to WhatsApp notification from java code in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, notifications

**Hello guys I'm using NotificationListenerService to get WhatsApp messages**

*But now I have a problem that I don't know how to replay to WhatsApp notifications*
*So here is the code and how I'm getting WhatsApp notifications but my problem is in how actually to replay on them*

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

// StaticFields:
public static final String WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.whatsapp";
// TAGS:
private static final String TAG = "NotificationListener";
private static final String NP_FIELD = "onNotificationPosted: ";

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    // Fields:
    ARPreferencesManager manager = new ARPreferencesManager(getApplicationContext());
    String currentPackages = manager.getStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.PACKAGE_APP_NAME);
    List<Chat.Messages> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    // CheckingStatusBarNotification:
    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals(WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
        // Initializing(DateTime):
        String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
        List<Chat> chats;
        // Initializing(Data):
        String sender = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String msg = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
        String currentSenders = manager.getStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.SENDER_NAME);
        // AddingData:
        messages.add(new Chat.Messages(msg));
        // Developing:
        if (manager.getPreferences().contains(ARPreferencesManager.WHATSAPP_CHATS)) {
            // Initializing:
            chats = ARUtils.fromJsonToChats(manager.getStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.WHATSAPP_CHATS));
            // Developing:
            for (Chat chat : chats) {
                if (chat.getSender().equals(sender)) {
                    // AddingTheNewMessage:
                    chat.getMessages().addAll(messages);
                    // AddingSender($Preferences):
                    if (!currentSenders.contains(sender)) {
                        // Initializing:
                        manager.setStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.SENDER_NAME, sender + ",");
                        // Refreshing:
                        currentSenders = manager.getStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.SENDER_NAME);
                    }
                }
            }
            // CheckingSenders:
            if (!currentSenders.contains(sender)) {
                // Initializing:
                Chat chat = new Chat(sender, "", date, null, messages);
                // AddingTheNewChat:
                chats.add(chat);
            }
        } else {
            // Initializing:
            chats = new ArrayList<>();
            // Developing:
            chats.add(new Chat(sender, "", date, null, messages));
        }
        // SettingPreferences:
        manager.setStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.WHATSAPP_CHATS, ARUtils.fromChatsToJson(chats));
        // Debugging:
        ARUtils.debug(TAG, NP_FIELD, manager.getStringPreferences(ARPreferencesManager.WHATSAPP_CHATS));
    }
    // Debugging:
    ARUtils.debug(TAG, NP_FIELD, "Whatsapp Package Was Founded In Preferences");
    // Debugging:
    ARUtils.debug(TAG, NP_FIELD, "Start");
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815024/auto-reply-to-whatsapp-message-in-background

Comment: https://github.com/suyashm002/watsappp_bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using this function?

```kotlin
fun reply(action: Notification.Action, message: String, exception: Exception.() -> Unit = {}) {
    try {
        val sendIntent = Intent()
        val msg = Bundle()
        for (inputable in action.remoteInputs) {
            msg.putCharSequence(inputable.resultKey, message)
        }
        RemoteInput.addResultsToIntent(action.remoteInputs, sendIntent, msg)
        action.actionIntent.send(applicationContext, 0, sendIntent)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        exception(exception)
    }
}
```

You can get `Notification.Action` for this way:

```kotlin
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)
    val wExt = Notification.WearableExtender(sbn.notification)
    for (action in wExt.actions) {
        ...
```

Comment: I'll try it thanks for help .. but first I have to convert this code to java then trying it.