# Android share via Intent not working,

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to be able to send text to a whatsapp contact, stack overflow seems to unanimously agree that this works:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "<number>"); 
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOOOH");
// sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

If .setType("text/plain"); is commented out, it just opens whatsapp to the chat of the number I gave it, but if I don't comment it out, nothing happens at all, any help appreciated.

Comment: because you have specifically mentioned to use whatsapp by doing this `sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");`

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42186169/3952238) SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

**change and add the last line remove the comment of sendIntent.setType**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "<number>"); 
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOOOH");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

// this line helps to open the chooser dialog
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share)));
```

Comment: edited the answer 
**removed the line** 
sendIntent.setpackage("com.whatsapp");

Comment: R.string.share_using?

Comment: R.string.share doesnt exist by default, what should I make its value in the xml?

Comment: no, you have to type the R.string.share which will import the android system resources file to the project (not your projects R), 

**ex: android.support.v7.appcompat.R.string.abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application**

I am using target sdk 22

Comment: Im using sdk 19 as I have android 4.4.2, when I try build the project it says   "cannot find symbol variable share"

Comment: Do I have  to do Emdad's process of  elimination? can I not just add a xml definiton in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Sorry that Im so confused, this is my first time coding for android

Comment: you can also look @QuokMoon's answer, but according to your need you can customize, and unfortunately sharing via intent is done only programmatically

Comment: "and unfortunately sharing via intent is done only programmatically " but cant I hardcode whatsapp's string instead of R.string.share?

Comment: add "share via" instead of R.string.share and let me know the feedback

Answer (score 0):

> Look at this code snippet that one also handled case if user not installed
>   whatsApp.

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
                    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
                    //in catch block will be called
                    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
```