# How to set a text as a description (about) in Whatsapp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to set a text as a description or your status like "available" in Whatsapp . I use `Intent` but it opens a selection page in Whatsapp if I want to share this text through story or send it to someone . That's because `ACTION_SEND`. Is there some type of action or any solution for my problem ?

Here is my code

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
            whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean  by description?

Comment: I mean "about" or your status like available  .

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WhatsApp FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)

> There are two ways to integrate with WhatsApp:
>
> -Through a custom URL scheme
>
> -Through Android's intent system.

**Custom URL Scheme**

> If you want to open a WhatsApp chat with a
>   pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so.
>   Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open
>   WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input
>   field with the specified text.

Example

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=I%27m%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale
```

**Android intent system**

> Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share
>   media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example,
>   and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

OR

With this code you can open the whatsapp chat with the given number.

```
 void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
}
```

You cannot set user status programmatically.

You can also see these for some more details:

1. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)
2. [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

Comment: Thank you for your answer  , but when I use `Intent` It doesn't show me the about page in whatsApp . How can I even show the about page ? I can't reach it when I use `Intent`

Comment: @Ahmed You can only send a prefilled text with an optional specific mobile number. Whats app does not provide any other api's.

Comment: Aha .. Is there any way to do that ? to edit the "about" like (available or something else ) in user'sWhatsApp ?

Comment: @Ahmed: No WhatsApp does not allow to do this. Do you have any other queries if not please accept this answer.

Comment: I can't vote up it because my reputation is less than 15 .

Comment: @Ahmed: MArk the answer as accepted then with a upvote :P.