# Can I open chat with an unknown contact?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I have an unknown number I need to start chat with it.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test")
                .putExtra("jid", "999999999@s.whatsapp.net")
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Whatsapp openы a window where I have to select a contact.

Is it possible to open Whatsapp and start a chat with it?

Comment: I would imagine WhatsApp can only start a chat with a contact that is in your WhatsApp contact list, if you specify number for contact you have on WhatsApp does it work?

Comment: If I send an intent to a contact which I have in my contact list, it works.

Comment: As suspected, it must be in your WhatsApp contacts

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419223/7803911)

```
String phone = "79999999999";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?phone=" + phone));
startActivity(intent);
```

Phone should be without any characters only digits. This number is valid **79999999999**, this number is not valid **+79999999999**