# Open conversation based on clicked number then intent the image

Tags: android, image, android-intent, kotlin, whatsapp

I know this is a common question that has been asked. But my problem is different now. So I create a share button which if I click it will open list of phone number like below :

[image: List of phone number]

So when I click one of them, it will immediately open conversation in whats app base on the phone number I click. I use this code

```
 val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62"+tempDatas!![position].custHpWa
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,intent.getStringExtra("DESCRIPTION") );
                                intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                                startActivity(intent);
```

Then I add this code for intent image into the conversation

```
 rvListWa!!.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerItemClickListener(this@ShareFileActivity,
            RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener { view, position ->

                Glide
                        .with(this@ShareFileActivity)
                        .load(baseURLPicasso+intent.getStringExtra("PICTURE"))
                        .asBitmap()
                        .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap?, glideAnimation: GlideAnimation<in Bitmap>?) {

                                val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62"+tempDatas!![position].custHpWa
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,intent.getStringExtra("DESCRIPTION") );
                                val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), resource, "", null);
                                val image = Uri.parse(path);

                                intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }

                        })
            }))
```

Instead of open conversation base on number and send image. It turns out open whats app and choose to who we want to send it.

Is there any solution. Because I already try to make the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` it will open gallery.

My image url is from database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send text to specific contact programmatically (whatsapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works. Just pass the path the file location of the file variable and make sure you pass the correct phone number.

```
    val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.SEND")
    val f = File("path to the file")
    val uri = Uri.fromFile(f)
    sendIntent.component = ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker")
    sendIntent.type = "image"
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("91**********") + "@s.whatsapp.net")
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample text you want to send along with the image")
    startActivity(sendIntent)
```

Comment: it doesn't work sir @Nagendra.. when I click the whatsapp icon it do nothing

Comment: Does the phone number in your code match with your whatsapp contact number?

Comment: PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(tempDatas!![position].custHpWa) , custHpWa is 081944877002, indonesian code

Comment: i change this com.whatsapp.ContactPicker into com.whatsapp.Conversation, it works but only for opening the convo , but my number becoming +081944877002 also the image not include

Comment: make sure you pass the correct image url else it will show error message like error sharing media file.

Comment: yes the image url exactly correct bcs i already try it from my previous code. Do you have any idea why the number include + ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184006/discussion-between-nagendra-hari-karthick-and-ratri).

Comment: check my message