# I am getting "+" prefix when I am sending message through my android app programmatically

Tags: java, android

My Efforts :-

Sometimes it shows number is not registered on whatsapp because of the "+" that I have'nt added into it

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + "998236XXXX" + "&text=" + "Hello");

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I have tried
[Send text to specific contact programmatically (whatsapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)

Comment: Could we see how you're obtaining the number?

Comment: statically @DannyBuonocore