# How to send contact info to Whatsapp from my application?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a message to Whatsapp from another app, that I achieved with the following code, and it's working fine:

To send simple messages refer: [Send text to specific contact programmatically (whatsapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)

```
fun sendWhatsappMessage(phone: String, message: String) {
    val packageManager = packageManager
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    try {
        val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phone&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(
            message,
            "UTF-8"
        )
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            sendBroadcast(i)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

My question is, is there a way to send a complex message, such as contact info through the message?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send contact using the vcard uri from contacts:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, <contact key>);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Charlinho"); // Input contact name
```