# How to send message to a number using whatsapp programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to open up a chat with the phone number (phone) by default when a user clicks a button.
but it is not starting at all.

```
case R.id.nav_chat:             
       PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
       Intent whatsapp_intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

       try {
             String phone = "123456789";
             String message = "Hello, can you help with my issues?";
             String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ phone +"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
             whatsapp_intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
             whatsapp_intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
             if (whatsapp_intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                 getApplication().startActivity(whatsapp_intent);
             }
        } catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
}
```

The answer to this question appears here originally 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821831/12632081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `Intent` action as `ACTION_VIEW` and not `ACTION_SEND`

```
Intent whatsapp_intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Also You should use the local `Context` and not the application `context`

```
//get it from your activity as `this` or from your fragment as: getActivity().getContext()
context.startActivity(whatsapp_intent);
```

Comment: thank you, will this method also work for email? like to programatically  fill in a default address

Comment: For email you will need a different Intent with action `ACTION_SEND` but it should work fine. Something to consider is that if you  have more than one email client app android will prompt the user to chose. Here is a useful example hope it solves your problem: 
https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-send-email-in-android-using-intent