# Whatsapp text group share on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, share, whatsapp

How can I share text - with a group - from my app - on whatsapp?

Whatsapp's current iPhone API (see here: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Enables to share text with a specific contact - Option #1 in the above link, 'custom URL scheme'

And enables to share image, video and audio documents with contacts *and* groups - Option #2 in the above link, 'iOS Document Interaction API'

How do I combine the two? How do I send simple text to a group?

This is the same issue as the following question, but for iPhone:
[How to share text to WhatsApp from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952865/i-want-to-share-my-text-with-whatsapp-from-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't, using either UIDocumentInteractionController or the WhatsAapp custom url scheme.

I Think there is no relation between a Whatsapp group and an ABGroup.