# How to share GIF image in Whatsapp programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, whatsapp

WhatsApp have added new feature display GIF.

if any one know how to share GIF in whatsapp then let me know

Comment: If you have tried anything yourself, please let us know!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952865/how-to-share-text-to-whatsapp-from-my-app

Comment: thanks for replay 

I already share GIF image in all social media but now whatsapp have new feature to display GIF with animation

so now share GIF in whatsapp with animation can you please help me if you know any about new whatsapp GIF feature

Comment: I have posted a similar question related to this problem...but i want to use whatsapp mp4 format that this app show as gif inside chats UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893316/whatsapp-video-as-gif-sharing-on-android-programatically

Comment: I upvoted because this is a helpful question and obviously it has generated a good amount of views.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
private void shareGif(String resourceName){

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";

    File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);

    try {
        byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
        InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sharingGifFile);
        int i = fis.read(readData);

        while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(readData, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(readData);
        }

        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
}
```

For share gif on whatsapp

```
/*  Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title + "\n\nLink : " + link );
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(sharePath));
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(shareIntent);*/
```

Comment: thanks for answer but share GIF using this method GIF not animated just display image. I am talk about new whatsapp feature

Comment: setType("image/gif"); replace the type and try it please

Comment: I also try using setType("image/gif") but not animating GIF still display simple Image

Comment: resourceName please?

Comment: Your file name that you want to share Gif image

Comment: will also depend on the whatsapp version you are using. Some builds don't support gif features.

Comment: This code is only sharing gif images if it located in drawable folder, but what if the image located in external or internal storage, I mean to get file from path and then share it. Help please

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the type of image intent as gif like below

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
```

Comment: i tried this, not working only still image shared not the animated gif.