# GIF is getting shared as an image not animated - Android Java

Tags: java, android, animated-gif

I am trying to share an GIF programmatically, but it is getting shared as an image (not animated)

Code Snippet:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setType("image/gif");//image/gif
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(myList.get(item)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share gif"));
```

Comment: Shared by who ?

Comment: Android (Java) yo share on any app :ex whatsapp  @blackapps

Comment: Are you telling that if you send a gif with gmail to me that i willl not receive the original gif? Hard to believe.

Comment: the problem was in file provider
here is the solicitation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: No. The problem then was you exposed a file uri which threw a FIleUriExposedException before even the provider was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to share to which apps?

*Some whatsapp builds don't support gif feature.*

You can check this question here with some additional information: [How to share GIF image in Whatsapp programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656663/how-to-share-gif-image-in-whatsapp-programmatically-in-android)

There is this comment:

"*This solution doesn't work with whatsapp but does work with all the other apps I specified above (namely Hangouts, Android Messages, Facebook Messenger)*"

He is referring to this answer:

```
private void ShareGif() {

  // replace the path and file name with your gif image path and name
  String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
  String fileName = "temporary_file.gif";

  File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);

  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));

}

/*
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title + "\n\nLink : " + link );
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(sharePath));
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(shareIntent);
*/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can mark the answer as the correct one if it solved your issue.