# Sharing TextView content with relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using `relativelayout`. somehow I couldn't find sharing the `TextView` content .. even if I found it I couldn't. I want to share the TextView content with a button, can you help me with this?

I haven't written java code yet.

I need share code for this `TextView`. attention i am using `relativelayout`

Code main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/k"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough what do you want to do? and what you got?

Comment: For example, I want to share TextView content on WhatsApp

Comment: android studio share button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share text to WhatsApp from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952865/how-to-share-text-to-whatsapp-from-my-app)

Comment: just this WhatsApp example. I'm looking for something valid in other apps

Answer (score 1):

You can create an implicit `ACTION_SEND` intent to open the app chooser, and pick the suitable app that you want to share the text with.

Use this method in an activity:

```
public void shareText(String title, String content) {
    
    // Create an ACTION_SEND Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    
    // Set the type of the content to "text"
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    
    // Adding extras to the intent (title & content) 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
    
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title));
}
```

Comment: Err startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title));.  Error : this method can not be referenced from a static-contect

Comment: @Cebom25 just remove `static` I fixed it now

Comment: I don't understand where I will change

Comment: Excuse me.. I just fixed it in code remove the `static` keyword from the the method signature .. I did it already . you can just copy and paste it

Comment: Unfortunately the application closes directly

Comment: String title, String content ? Do I need to create a string?

Comment: You can add abstract text if you wish... or get a string from resources using `getString()`